# Is there a way to margin an anchor in css?

Tags: html, css, anchor

I have a fixed header height 50px. In my body, I have a lot of anchors. The problem is that, when I click on links pointing to anchors, the anchor appears under my fixed header and I lose 50px of content (I need to scroll up of 50px to read content under the header).

Is there a way to margin an anchor of 50px? My body is filled with a lot of box (divs) with a margin between themself, so I can't put in place an empty div of 50px and then anchor after it..

html:

```
<div id="header"></div>
<div id="content">
     <div class="box" id="n1"></div>
     <div class="box" id="n2"></div>
     <div class="box" id="n3"></div>
</div>
```

css:

```
#header{
    height: 40px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    position: fixed;
    text-align: center;
    z-index:2;
}

#content{
    padding-top: 50px; 
    margin: 0px;
}

.box {
    width: 80%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    vertical-align : top;
    padding: 1.4%; /* Keep it in percent (%) */
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    min-height: 200px;
}
```

Comment: this could help Anchor Links with a Fixed Header:
http://www.pixelflips.com/blog/anchor-links-with-a-fixed-header/

Comment: "In my body, I have a lot of anchors." :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the header is truly fixed then place your anchors in a scrollable div. Then the div containing the anchor will scroll instead of the entire page. Visit the fiddle and click on anchor1. It goes to anchor2. And so forth.

http://jsfiddle.net/mrtsherman/CsJ3Y/3/

css - set overflow hidden on body to prevent default scrolling. Use position absolute on the new content area with top and bottom set. This forces it to stretch to fit the remaining viewport window.

```
body { overflow: hidden; }
#header { position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 50px; background: gray; border: 1px solid black; }
#content { 
    overflow: scroll; 
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid blue; 
}
```

html

```
<div id="header">header</div>
<div id="content">
    <div>
        Page Content <br />
        <a id="a1" href="#anchor2" name="anchor1">Anchor 1</a>                
        <a id="a2" href="#anchor1" name="anchor2">Anchor 2</a>   
    </div>
</div>​
```

Comment: I updated my initial post. Look at my code.. I tried with overflow-y: scroll but, it still not working..

Comment: Overflow-y is not supported in all browsers.

Comment: @mrtsherman I When I click anchor1, I need to view "Anchor1" and its content. Same for anchor2..

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/CsJ3Y/1/ It works well with firefox, but It does not work with chrome

Comment: It's just an example. You can't add hashmarks to the url in jsfiddle. The hash targets whatever element has either that `id` or `name` in your html. So if you swapped the href values they would go to themselves.

Comment: @Pier-alexandreBouchard - what doesn't work? Seems to work fine for me.

Comment: Are you using chrome or FF ? Both works, but content is a little bit under the header (test1 and test2, in the update I gave you)

Comment: I tried both. They look the same to me and the anchors work in both.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/CsJ3Y/1/ With firefox, The middle top of "test" and "test2" is hidden under Firefox and everything is hidden with chrome..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7874/discussion-between-mrtsherman-and-pier-alexandre-bouchard)

Answer (score 22):

Welcome to the future:

```
.box {
  scroll-margin-top: 50px;
}
```

Source: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/s/scroll-margin/

Answer (score 4):

If you use jQuery, you use this function:

```
function scrollToAnchor() {
    if($(".jquery-anchor").length > 0 && document.URL.indexOf("#") >= 0){
    var anchor = document.URL.split("#")[1];
    $(".jquery-anchor").each(function() {
        if($(this).attr("name") == anchor) {
            $("html,body").animate({
                    scrollTop: $(this).offset().top - 50},
                'slow');
            }
        });
    }
}
```

then add the class "jquery_anchor" to your anchor

Comment: I'm missing something.  What calls 'scrollToAnchor()' ??

Comment: I put this in a function to make it work in ajax. It is called on document load via $(document).ready() but also after each ajax round trip via callbacks.

Comment: I finally figured that out.. in fact I added:  
  // Intercept all anchor clicks
  jQuery("body").on("click", "a", scrollToAnchor);

Answer (score 4):

For Pure CSS solution just use another div with oposited margin :)

```
<style>
.anchor {
     margin-top: -50px; 
     margin-bottom: 50px;
}
</style>

<div id="n1" class="anchor"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// For modern browsers, just add the CSS3 :target selector to the page. 
// This will apply to all the anchors automatically.
// ref: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21707103/6220029

:target {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    top: -120px; 
    visibility: hidden;}
```

Comment: This is a great answer

Answer (score 0):

It is an old thread, i know - but maybe other people has the same question.

An Opportunity is setting a top padding to each anchored div like this:

.box{
padding-top: 50px;
...
}

Now your anchor scroll will reach the box without any empty containers before, and the padding you add in CSS will give you the space to show the content directly under your header.